# Cannot call a function that returns Result: found opaque type impl std::future::Future

Tags: rust, reqwest, rust-result

I cannot return a result of a function from a `Result`. Every tutorial only shows how to use a Result, but not how to return a value from it.

```
fn main(){
    let mut a: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    a = gottem();
    println!("{}", a.len().to_string());
    //a.push(x.to_string()
}
async fn gottem() -> Result<Vec<String>, reqwest::Error> {
    let mut a: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    let res = reqwest::get("https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/")
        .await?
        .text()
        .await?;
    Document::from(res.as_str())
        .find(Name("a"))
        .filter_map(|n| n.attr("href"))
        .for_each(|x| println!("{}", x));
    Ok(a)
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:13:9
   |
13 |     a = gottem();
   |         ^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::vec::Vec`, found opaque type
...
18 | async fn gottem() -> Result<Vec<String>, reqwest::Error> {
   | ----------------------------------- the `Output` of this `async fn`'s found opaque type
   |
   = note:   expected struct `std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>`
       found opaque type `impl std::future::Future`
```

Comment: If you don't know how to use `async` (because you can't use it the way you are trying to use it) or even `Result`, one of the most fundamental Rust type, you've probably missed a few steps in your tutorials. In particular, [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) covers `Result` and the different ways to get data out of it pretty well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Your function doesn't return a `Result`, it returns a `Future<Result>` (because it's an async function), [you need to feed it into an executor (e.g. `block_on`)](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/01_getting_started/04_async_await_primer.html) in order to run it; alternatively, use [`reqwest::blocking`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.6/reqwest/blocking/index.html) as it's easier if you don't care for the async bits
2. Once executor-ed, your function is returning a `Result` but you're trying to put it into a `Vec`, that can't work

Unrelated, but:

> ```
> println!("{}", a.len().to_string());
> ```

`{}` essentially does a `to_string` internally, the `to_string` call is not useful.